# React Native OneSignal: deviceState doesn't show subscribed until second time user logs in

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

In my React Native app, I initialize my OneSignal instance with `OneSignal.setAppId()`, and then attempt to grab the `UserID` using `OneSignal.getDeviceState()`. My code looks like this:

```
OneSignal.setAppId("<AppID>");
let getDeviceState = async () => {
  const deviceState = await OneSignal.getDeviceState()
  console.log(deviceState)
}
getDeviceState();
```

When I first install the app, it returns this:

```
{"hasNotificationPermission": true, "isEmailSubscribed": false, "isPushDisabled": false, "isSMSSubscribed": false, "isSubscribed": false}
```

On all subsequent loads, it returns this:

```
{"hasNotificationPermission": true, "isEmailSubscribed": false, "isPushDisabled": false, "isSMSSubscribed": false, "isSubscribed": true, "pushToken": <...>, "userId": <...>}
```

So on the first load, I can't access `pushToken` or `userId`. Is it just that they haven't had time to load yet? Is there an event handler I can access when they do?

`react-native@0.64.4`
`react-native-onesignal@4.0.6`